# Append subscript to variable name

Tags: replacement, symbols

I'm importing equations from Word document and transforming them into input form. But subscripts look ugly.

Is is possible to programmatically append subscript to variable name?

e.g.

AppendSub[Subscript[a, 1]]=a1

Comment: or even `Array[x, 10] /. x_[k_] :> Subscript[x, k]`?

Comment: sorry for confusion, I clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, one way is to use patterns and replacement rules (check out [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Symbol.html)):

```
{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], 
  Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5], Subscript[x, 6], Subscript[x, 7], 
  Subscript[x, 8], Subscript[x, 9], Subscript[x, 10]} /. 
 Subscript[x_, k_] :> Symbol[ToString[x] <> StringReplace[ToString[k]," "->""]]
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10} *)
```

as a function you can use:

```
appendSub[exp_] := 
 exp /. Subscript[x_, k_] :> Symbol[ToString[x] <> StringReplace[ToString[k]," "->""]]

appendSub[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 
  3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5], Subscript[x, 6], Subscript[x, 
  7], Subscript[x, 8], Subscript[x, 9], Subscript[x, 10]}]
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10} *)
```

Comment: StringReplace[ToString[k]," "->""] helps with subscripts that have spaces